# Parse error: Really Can't Figure This One Out

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, syntax

NEW ERROR!! 
Thanks guys! worked, but new error popped up on line 55 :( im gonna edit, and mark the line number with "// LINE 55", in my original post ^^

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in C:\wamp\www\flueforumdk\config.php on line 55
```

I get a parse error when trying to make a function, my timestamp code worked well before i tried to put it in a function so i can re-use it without making a big mess in my code.
I get the unix time from a mysql database from 'cmd.php', and have my function in 'config.php' here's my error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''$UNIX_TIME_SECONDS'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\flueforumdk\config.php on line 33
```

HERE'S MY CODE IN 'CMD.PHP':

```
$GET_UNIX_STAMP_FROM_DB = $art[tidspunkt];
$UNIX_TIME_SECONDS = $GET_UNIX_STAMP_FROM_DB;

echo timestamp_converter($UNIX_TIME_SECONDS);
```

AND HERE'S MY CODE IN 'CONFIG.PHP':

```
## TIMESTAMP CONVERTER FUNCTION
function timestamp_converter('$UNIX_TIME_SECONDS'){
          // UDREGNING FRA UNIX TIME
          $tid = time() - $UNIX_TIME_SECONDS;
          $timer = floor($tid/3600);
          $minutter = floor($tid/60);
          $dage = floor($timer / 24);
          $uge = floor($dage / 7);
          $month = floor($dage / 30.5);
          $aar = floor($dage / 365);
     if($tid < 60){
       echo"<b>$tid</b> sekunder";
     } elseif ($tid > 60){
       echo"";
       } // THIS IS LINE 33
     if($minutter == 0){
       echo"";
     } elseif ($minutter < 60){
     if($minutter == 1){
       echo"<b>$minutter</b> minut";
     }else{
       echo"<b>$minutter</b> minutter";
     }
     }
         if($timer == 0){
       echo"";
     } elseif ($timer < 24){
     if($timer == 1){
       echo"<b>$timer</b> time";
       }else{
echo"<b>$timer</b> timer";
}
}
    //LINE 55   if($dage == 0){
echo"";
} elseif ($dage < 7){
if($dage == 1){
echo"<b>$dage</b> dag";
}else{
echo"<b>$dage</b> dage";
}
}
  if($uge == 0){
echo"";
} elseif ($uge < 4){
if($uge == 1){
echo"<b>$uge</b> uge";
}else{
echo"<b>$uge</b> uger";
}
}
   if($month == 0){
echo"";
} elseif ($month < 12){
if($month == 1){
echo"<b>$month</b> måned";
}else{
echo"<b>$month</b> måneder";
}
}
    if($aar == 0){
echo"";
} elseif ($aar > 0){
if($aar == 1){
echo"<b>$aar</b> år";
}else{
echo"<b>$aar</b> år";
}
}
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the code that generates your SQL query?

Comment: After your edit, Can you tell us which is line 55? I'm not seeing a `.` character that could cause any problems...

Comment: After your edit: Please check the code of the config.php you posted. There seems to be syntactically all right.

Answer (score 5):

The line

```
function timestamp_converter('$UNIX_TIME_SECONDS'){
```

must be

```
function timestamp_converter($UNIX_TIME_SECONDS){
```

without the quotation marks, as this is the incoming parameter and no concrete value at this point.

Answer (score 4):

Change your function declaration to...

```
function timestamp_converter($UNIX_TIME_SECONDS){
```

Answer (score 0):

If your line creating the function, you should only be using single quotes when predefining a variable for the function. This is the only time you need to use quotes like this while declaring a function.

```
function example ($DATA = 'data') {}
function example ($UNIX_TIME_SECONDS = 'predefine it here if you need to') {}
```